# how to set value to zero of key-value pair object which i got in firebase cloud function(snapshot)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

i have created cloud function which will trigger `onCreate()` when new value is add to node `Sample/Pen`.whenever the new node is created in `Sample/Pen`, i wanted to create another node which is `Final/Pen` but the values of key-value pair should be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the job:

```
exports.finalPen = functions.database
  .ref('/Sample/Pen/{penId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const createdData = snap.val(); // data that was created

    return admin
      .database()
      .ref('Final/Pen/' + snap.key)
      .set(setAllToZero(createdData));
  });

const setAllToZero = function(pen) {
  Object.keys(pen).forEach(function(key) {
    pen[key] = 0;
  });
  return pen;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Man, you saved my life :D